# PHP store variable even after session ends

Tags: php

Is there a way to keep the variable even after the page is closed? i tried by making it a `static` variable but this doesn't work, I think I understand static wrong.

Comment: For this purpose use `cookies`.

Comment: @u_mulder yes, use cookie but remember that cookies are client side and can be deleted. So, if he want to store something more *consistent*, maybe, he can store a variable elsewhere (database?) if user authentication is expected in this logic

Comment: @DonCallisto thanks for further clarification)

Answer (score 0):

Yes , if the session cookies are not deleted or expired after the closing the page, please put the cookies life time for your required hours..